# symfony 2 command issue

Tags: php, symfony, command

I am trying to run a php script form the command line.

```
sudo vim  UpdateLatestIssuesCommand.php
```

But its giving me the following error:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Command\ContainerAwareCommand' not found in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/imagine-publishing/src/Imagine/CorporateBundle/Command/UpdateLatestIssuesCommand.php on line 12
```

I cant figure out why I am getting this error because the file its says it cant find is actually there.

Heres my code:

```
<?php

namespace Imagine\CorporateBundle\Command;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Command\ContainerAwareCommand;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputArgument;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputOption;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Output\OutputInterface;

class UpdateLatestIssuesCommand extends ContainerAwareCommand
{
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to run the command like this

```
php app/console demo:greet Fabien
```

where, demo:greet is the name of the command, Fabien is the argument

**Reason**
Because, console component has to bootstrap required resources for you before it runs the command.

FYI: [Console Component](http://symfony.com/doc/master/components/console/introduction.html)

Comment: Ok thanks, how do I find out what the name of the command and argument?

Comment: @richelliot you use the `configure` function -> http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/console/console_command.html